# Working with Eclipse(Android) strange errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am still learning to code, but apps i code persistently can't work on 2 diferent devices. Can Eclipse (latest android sdk) be the error or i code wrong every single app?
Its force close on 2 devices

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Button dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Cao();
        }   
        });



}
private void Cao(){
    Intent Cao = new Intent(this, Cao.class);
    startActivity(Cao);
}}
```

This is Cao class

```
    public class Cao  extends Activity{


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cao);
}}
```

And Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.book1"
    android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.book1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity
        android:name="com.example.book1.Cao"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.Action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      </application></manifest>
```

Comment: Force close on 2 devices

Comment: A force close isn't an error, it's a problem. We need to know exactly *how* it crashed, not _that_ it crashed

Comment: check persmission, clean project,
restart eclipse..... Sometimes weird things happen in android world...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to put

```
Button dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme);
```

this line in your `onCreate` method. A class shoud have only variables and methods. This line is definition. So I think that is only problem in your code.  Other than there is nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: that is the problem for sure. This line will be executed on construction, which means it won't find any ID and dugme will be null! Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Put this line

```
Button dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme)
```

After

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

> Android  takes each reference of view_id according to its each layout xml

Think if android takes view reference_id  before setting up layout to the given activity then we can not  even  keep same name of view ID  for two different  layout xml .

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
Button dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme);
```

not because it not located in the `onCreate` method, but because it appears before this line:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

And the reason for that is: if you didn't set your layout as the content view of your activity you can't use the `findViewById` method, because there is no place that this view could be found (you layout is not yet set).